# How should I replace this line "provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath" for a "Kind" statefulset.yaml file?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, cassandra, yaml, kind

The following is a `StatefulSet.yaml` file for deploying `Cassandra` database on a `minikube` cluster. I am not sure what lines should be replaced if I want to use a `Kind` cluster instead of a `minikube` one, but I think one obvious option would be `provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
  labels:
    app: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1800
      containers:
      - name: cassandra
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7000
          name: intra-node
        - containerPort: 7001
          name: tls-intra-node
        - containerPort: 7199
          name: jmx
        - containerPort: 9042
          name: cql
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - nodetool drain
        env:
          - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
            value: 512M
          - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
            value: 100M
          - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
            value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"
          - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
            value: "K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_DC
            value: "DC1-K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
            value: "Rack1-K8Demo"
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /ready-probe.sh
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        # These volume mounts are persistent. They are like inline claims,
        # but not exactly because the names need to match exactly one of
        # the stateful pod volumes.
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cassandra-data
          mountPath: /cassandra_data
  # These are converted to volume claims by the controller
  # and mounted at the paths mentioned above.
  # do not use these in production until ssd GCEPersistentDisk or other ssd pd
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: fast
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fast
provisioner: k8s.io/minikube-hostpath
parameters:
  type: pd-ssd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default storage class provided by Kind i.e, **standard** storageclass. To use a default storage class either you can specify the `storageClassName: standard` or remove the `storageClassName` line in PVC.

In your case remove the storage class name from PVC template and remove the storage class creation part.

```
 volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: cassandra-data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

This should be enough to create a PVC with the **default** storage class.

To know more about kinD Storageclasses refer to this [blog](https://mauilion.dev/posts/kind-pvc/)

To know more about default storage class refer the default storage class section in this [official k8 document](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-classes-kubernetes/)

Comment: Before you answer my question, I replaced that line with `provisioner: kubernetes.io/host-path` and it seems it worked! Did I do a wrong thing?

Comment: Hi @best_of_man if you are creating a manual storageclass that is absolutely fine.